# Excel - for cells that are true find date and determine the max

Tags: excel, indexing

I have a data set that looks like this:

[image]

Each date corresponds with a True/ False value.
In excel, I'm trying to identify the largest true date. I've tried:
max(INDEX(dates,MATCH(TRUE,variables,0)))

But this isn't resulting in what I want. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: You don't need helper columns. 
   =TEXT(MAX(NUMBERVALUE(TEXT(A2:C2,"mm/dd/yyyy"))),"d-mmm-yy")

Comment: @Ethan the "helper" columns are not helper columns but criteria on whether to consider the date in the max or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use MAXIFS:

```
=MAXIFS(A2:C2,E2:G2,TRUE)
```

[image]

If one does not have MAXIFS, then use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,(A2:C2)/(E2:G2),1)
```

[image]

or if even older version the array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(E2:G2,A2:C2))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: THX SO MUCH!!! i'm working off excel'16 so aggregate worked perfectly!

Comment: @kr777 please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.